# How to store returned result using mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to this community. May be this is a simple question but i have no idea how to store returned result of mysql query in an array which is of OUT parameter type using stored procedure.

Example: I am fetching some data from mysql database `(select * from users)` and it is returning an array. And I have to pass that array as an OUT parameter of stored procedure, how can i do that?

Can anyone suggest me good tutorial or reference for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to write the procedure or how to call it from a secondary language?

Comment: Can you explain me with the syntax and one example?

Comment: @ethrbunny I have added an example. Please see if you can suggest me any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an ARRAY datatype in SQL. You can return other values via OUT params though (INT, VARCHAR, etc).

Your query will return a `resultset`. You can either deal with this inside the procedure using a cursor, put it into another (temporary) table or just exit.